# Customer cross platform date picker with HTML5

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

I am using the date input type in HTML 5 and wanted to customize the look, i found a bunch of code but they all seem to be Webkit pseudo-elements, meaning they'll only work with Webkit browser such as Chrome.

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper 
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text 
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field 
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field 
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field  
::-webkit-inner-spin-button 
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator
```

They are the pseudo-elements elements that i found (Haven't really check if it's a complete list).

Now my question is, how do i make the custom styling for the date input cross platform? Do browser like IE, Firefox and Opera have there own pseudo-elements to achieve this sort of customization?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest jQuery UI's datepicker. It requires JavaScript/jQuery but quite simple to install and works great on all platforms even on mobile devices. Check out here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/